# I can only get part of a url (link) and put into string in android?

Tags: android, url, android-glide

**[Solved]**  - **I need to resolve the problem below**
Ok I wasn't really sure how to word this question, but basically what I want to do is, I got a url from a RSS feed in android, and I need to put part of that url into a string, the url will look something like this: `http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821'` and I only want the part after id= **ONLY THE ID NUMBER**,Then I need the id to put it in the following url: `http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/**ID HERE**/download/tvmap.jpg`, to load the image corresponding to the id in Glide: **[Solved]** This Part is solved but i have a other Problem

I have to ways to do this

**First Way:**

```
 //the original String
    String somestring = "http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821";
    //save the index of the string '=' since after that is were you find your number, remember to add one as the begin index is inclusive
    int beginIndex = somestring.indexOf("=") + 1;
    //if the number ends the string then save the length of the string as the end, you can change this index if that's not the case
    int endIndex = somestring.length();
    //Obtain the substring using the indexes you obtained (if the number ends the string you can ignore the second index, but i leave it here so you may use it if that's not the case)
    String theNumber = somestring.substring(beginIndex,endIndex);
    //printing the number for testing purposes
    System.out.println("The number is: " + theNumber);
    //Then create a new string with the data you want (I recommend using StringBuilder) with the first part of what you want
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/");
    // add the number
    sb.append(theNumber);
    //then the rest of the string
    sb.append("/download/tvmap.jpg");
    //Saving the String in a variable
    String endResult = sb.toString();
    //Verifying end result 
    System.out.println("The end result is: "+endResult);

Glide.with(context).load(endResult).into(holder.Thumbnail);
```

**Second Way:**

```
String url = "http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821";
    String[] array = url.split("id=");
    String id  = array[1];
    String urlToLoad = "http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/"+id+"/download/tvmap.jpg"
    Glide.with(context).load(urlToLoad).into(holder.Thumbnail);
```

**[Problem]**

My problem is, if i put the URL normally, ie `http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821` the two methods work for me, but if I get the url Via `getLink()` does not work for me. **Please help me.

I hope I explained well. 
Thanks in advance**.

There is my **Myadapter.java** the method to get the link is **`current.getLink()`**

```
package com.example.rssreader;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.Techniques;
import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.YoYo;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Efrain on 26-02-2016.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
    Context context;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems){
        this.feedItems=feedItems;
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).playOn(holder.cardView);
        FeedItem current=feedItems.get(position);
        holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.Description.setText(current.getDescription());
        holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
        holder.Link.setText(current.getLink());
        //the original String
        String somestring = current.getLink();
        //save the index of the string '=' since after that is were you find your number, remember to add one as the begin index is inclusive
        int beginIndex = somestring.indexOf("=") + 1;
        //if the number ends the string then save the length of the string as the end, you can change this index if that's not the case
        int endIndex = somestring.length();
        //Obtain the substring using the indexes you obtained (if the number ends the string you can ignore the second index, but i leave it here so you may use it if that's not the case)
        String theNumber = somestring.substring(beginIndex,endIndex);
        //printing the number for testing purposes
        System.out.println("The number is: " + theNumber);
        //Then create a new string with the data you want (I recommend using StringBuilder) with the first part of what you want
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/");
        // add the number
        sb.append(theNumber);
        //then the rest of the string
        sb.append("/download/tvmap.jpg");
        //Saving the String in a variable
        String endResult = sb.toString();
        //Verifying end result
        System.out.println("The end result is: "+endResult);
        Glide.with(context).load(endResult).into(holder.Thumbnail);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Title,Description,Date,Link;
        ImageView Thumbnail;
        CardView cardView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            Description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
            Date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            Thumbnail= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_img);
            cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            Link= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print your log output... whats the output of System.out.println("The number is: " + theNumber); and 
        System.out.println("The end result is: "+endResult);

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
String url = "http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821";
String[] array = url.split("id=");
String id  = array[1];
String urlToLoad = "http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/"+id+"/download/tvmap.jpg"
Glide.with(context).load(urlToLoad).into(holder.Thumbnail);
```

Then use this id where you want to use

Comment: How put the in the second url and load it in Glide Please help me and I accept the answer

Comment: Just Update my answer

Comment: @EfrainJuniorValentin, create another question with your other problem and accept this one if it answered your first problem.

Comment: Btw its not good to accept an answer and then cancel it.. if you have any further issues create a new question for that  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that making a substring of the number you want to find and then appending that to the string you need.

The code would be as follows:

```
    //the original String
    String somestring = "http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Spanish/Informe_Sismo/myinfoGeneral.php?id=20161206012821";
    //save the index of the string '=' since after that is were you find your number, remember to add one as the begin index is inclusive
    int beginIndex = somestring.indexOf("=") + 1;
    //if the number ends the string then save the length of the string as the end, you can change this index if that's not the case
    int endIndex = somestring.length();
    //Obtain the substring using the indexes you obtained (if the number ends the string you can ignore the second index, but i leave it here so you may use it if that's not the case)
    String theNumber = somestring.substring(beginIndex,endIndex);
    //printing the number for testing purposes
    System.out.println("The number is: " + theNumber);
    //Then create a new string with the data you want (I recommend using StringBuilder) with the first part of what you want
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("http://shake.uprm.edu/~shake/archive/shake/");
    // add the number
    sb.append(theNumber);
    //then the rest of the string
    sb.append("/download/tvmap.jpg");
    //Saving the String in a variable
    String endResult = sb.toString();
    //Verifying end result 
    System.out.println("The end result is: "+endResult);
```

After that you can put the String into Glide
I hope It was clear and well explained.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: Hello Efrain. I would gladly help you but I would need to know why it didn't work. If the String is not returning perhaps the problem is in your FeedItem class not returning the string. If the String is returning from FeedItem but the code is not working please tell me why is not working.

Comment: The feed is working good, I display the link in a text view and it display correctly.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the error you are getting?

Comment: The picture is not displaying